# Solidity Gas Optimization dynamic function execution

Tags: optimization, dynamic, delegates, solidity, dynamic-execution

Anyone know which is more efficient dynamic function execution

```
function push(
    History storage self,
    function(uint256, uint256) view returns (uint256) op,
    uint256 delta
) internal returns (uint256, uint256) {
    return push(self, op(latest(self), delta));
}
```

or using an enum

```
function push(
    History storage self,
    uint8 operation
    uint256 delta
) internal returns (uint256, uint256) {
      if(operation == 1) {
          return push(self, latest(self) + delta);
     }
    return push(self, latest(self) - delta);
}
```